# Google Analytics Report tool Throwing Error

Tags: google-analytics

I have configured two sets of report, when I run both the reports gets failed. We have more than 20 apps using GA and we are facing this issue only with one particular app. Attaching screen shots below.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

[image]
error

[image]

Comment: What are you using to run those reports?   That's not a standard API error I think you should contact the author of the application.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm using https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about how to use Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on and is not programing related.